# django - import file from project into downloaded app within site-packages

Tags: python-import, django-2.0

I have a signal within an app on my project and i need to import it in an app I've downloaded which is stored with in site-packages. Is this possible?

```
myproject / 
  src /
    signals.py
  myprojectenv /
    lib / 
      python3.6 /
        site-packages /
           allauth /
             accounts /
               view.py
```

I want to bring a signal from src.signals into accounts.view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath)

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")
```